# Evidence of Linux reinstallation

Tags: linux, logging, reinstall

I know that the results of a system installation appear in /var/log/anaconda.log, however I am curious if this log will show any additional installations.

For example, if I have an existing Linux installation and then I reinstall (the same) Linux again, will the log file show that this process occurred again.  And, if so, is it easy to recognize?

Comment: Most likely it'll clear the whole drive and write a new log file. Depends on what the log has (timestamps etc?) you might notice. Why?

Comment: Honestly, I'm trying to figure out a way to determine if students in a class have successfully installed an OS on a virtual machine.  The caveat is that the VM already has Linux installed, and they will perform a reinstallation separate to class.  I want to ensure that they actually did the work and hoped I could find evidence of that on the system.

Comment: Use timestamps of key files to test this, or how about requiring they install a different variant of Linux - for example if it comes with CentOS, require an Ubuntu install or vice-versa.

Comment: delete /var/log/anaconda.log, you can use device creation/use time.

Comment: @davidgo: Unfortunately this is being driven through vsphere and dictated by an IT department (outside of my control), as is the version of Linux.

Comment: @Archemar: Do you mean for them to delete it prior to reinstalling? Wouldn't it be overwritten anyway by the install?

Comment: In that case you probably can't do what you are trying to do.   I guess you could go through an install, see the default way Linux is partitioned, require the students to partition it differently and then check that the new partitioning is different to the old one. (Linux offers a few different install partition options depending on the variant)

Comment: If I have them send me the anaconda.log, could I simply check the file creation date?